# How to encode newlines in vCard 4.0 parameter values: ^n or \n?

Tags: encoding, escaping, newline, vcf-vcard, carddav

The [vCard 4.0 RFC 6350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-6.3.1) says that Newlines in property parameter values must be encoded as \n (at least for LABEL parameter of ADR property):

```
  The property can also include a "LABEL" parameter to present a
  delivery address label for the address.  Its value is a plain-text
  string representing the formatted address.  Newlines are encoded
  as \n, as they are for property values.


  ADR;GEO="geo:12.3457,78.910";LABEL="Mr. John Q. Public, Esq.\n
  Mail Drop: TNE QB\n123 Main Street\nAny Town, CA  91921-1234\n
  U.S.A.":;;123 Main Street;Any Town;CA;91921-1234;U.S.A.
```

However vCard 4.0 RFC 6350 is updated by ['Parameter Value Encoding in iCalendar and vCard' RFC  6868](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6868#section-3), which says:

```
  formatted text line breaks are encoded into ^n (U+005E, U+006E)

  GEO;X-ADDRESS="Pittsburgh Pirates^n115 Federal St^nPitt
  sburgh, PA 15212":geo:40.446816,-80.00566
  being used
```

How do I encode newlines in vCard 4.0 parameter values as \n or as ^n?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual grammar:

```
param-value = *SAFE-CHAR / DQUOTE *QSAFE-CHAR DQUOTE
```

vCard/iCalendar (unfortunately) does not support generic escaping in property attribute values. As mentioned in RFC 6868:

> The \-escaping mechanism used for property text values is not defined
>   for use with parameter values

(which is the whole point of RFC 6868).

LABEL is special and explicitly spec'ed to support \n:

> The property can also include a "LABEL" parameter to present a
>   delivery address label for the address.  Its value is a plain-text
>   string representing the formatted address.  Newlines are encoded as
>   \n, as they are for property values.

This is just for LABEL.

To answer your question: "How do I encode newlines in vCard 4.0 parameter values as \n or as ^n?"

You first look whether the value of the parameter is spec'ed in a special way, like LABEL. If so, encode it as described for the parameter. If it isn't, encode it via ^.